# Gradle Test Dependency

Tags: testing, build, automated-tests, dependency-management, gradle

I have two projects, project A and Project B. Both are written in groovy and use gradle as their build system.

Project A requires project B. 
This holds for both the compile and test code.

How can I configure that the test classes of project A have access to the test classes of project B?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644011/multi-project-test-dependencies-with-gradle

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can expose the test classes via a 'tests' configuration and then define a testCompile dependency on that configuration.

I have this block for all java projects, which jars all test code:

```
task testJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: testClasses) {
    baseName = "test-${project.archivesBaseName}"
    from sourceSets.test.output
}

configurations {
    tests
}

artifacts {
    tests testJar
}
```

Then when I have test code I want to access between projects I use

```
dependencies {
    testCompile project(path: ':aProject', configuration: 'tests')
}
```

This is for Java; I'm assuming it should work for groovy as well.

Comment: Is there no other way to do this except compile test classes?

Comment: If I understand your question then yes, as far as I know you'll need to compile the test classes to use them as dependencies.

Comment: for later versions of Gradle (I'm using 1.3) the line "from sourceSets.test.classes" should read "from sourceSets.test.output"

Comment: There should have been some direct way to do it. This worked great for me nonetheless. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: This is kinda odd because it requires changing the depending module's configuration. There must be a way to access the classes (output) of the test compilation directly as a dependency.

Comment: To pull in all the transitive dependencies of the tests as well, I added:
    `configurations {
      tests { extendsFrom testRuntime }
    }`

Comment: How to achieve the same for the androidTest classes?

Comment: not working for me, always get - `Could not get unknown property 'testClasses'`

Comment: @djangofan ... We made an independent `ProjetnameTestingLibrary` sub-project.  Then the testCompile looks like: ``  testCompile project( ':ProjectnameTestingLibrary' ...`.  Any test helper classes and test resources are build in that sub-project.  This builds common test resources (code and data) across  several modules to test different aspects of the same feature.  Individual (spock) test specs are in the usual place.

Comment: Can you add a variant for Kotlin?

Answer (score 19):

This is a simpler solution that doesn't require an intermediate jar file:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  testCompile project(':aProject').sourceSets.test.output
}
```

There's more discussion in this question: [Multi-project test dependencies with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644011/multi-project-test-dependencies-with-gradle)

Comment: This breaks IDE integration and misses transitive dependencies. It also breaks encapsulation of projects, which is always a bad practice.

Answer (score 11):

**This is now supported as a first class feature in Gradle** (since 5.6)

Modules with `java` or `java-library` plugins can also include a `java-test-fixtures` **plugin** which exposes helper classes and resources to be consumed with testFixtures helper. Benefit of this approach against artifacts and classifiers are:

- proper dependency management (implementation/api)
- nice separation from test code (separate source set)
- no need to filter out test classes to expose only utilities
- maintained by Gradle

Example:

**:modul:one**

modul/one/build.gradle

```
plugins {
  id "java-library" // or "java"
  id "java-test-fixtures"
}

dependencies {
  testFixturesImplementation("your.jar:dependency:0.0.1")
}
```

or `lazyly` just add *all* dependencies of main `implementation` configuration:

```
val testFixturesImplementation by configurations.existing
val implementation by configurations.existing
testFixturesImplementation.get().extendsFrom(implementation.get())
```

modul/one/src/***testFixtures***/java/com/example/Helper.java

```java
package com.example;
public class Helper {}
```

**:modul:other**

modul/other/build.gradle

```
plugins {
  id "java" // or "java-library"
}
dependencies {
  testImplementation(testFixtures(project(":modul:one")))
}
```

modul/other/src/test/java/com/example/other/SomeTest.java

```java
package com.example.other;
import com.example.Helper;
public class SomeTest {
  @Test void f() {
    new Helper(); // used from :modul:one's testFixtures
  }
}
```

For more info, see the documentation:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures

Comment: "separate source set" is key here. This should be the answer.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me (Java)

```
// use test classes from spring-common as dependency to tests of current module
testCompile files(this.project(':spring-common').sourceSets.test.output)
testCompile files(this.project(':spring-common').sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath)

// filter dublicated dependency for IDEA export
def isClassesDependency(module) {
     (module instanceof org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.ModuleLibrary) && module.classes.iterator()[0].url.toString().contains(rootProject.name)
}

idea {
      module {
          iml.whenMerged { module ->
              module.dependencies.removeAll(module.dependencies.grep{isClassesDependency(it)})
              module.dependencies*.exported = true
          }
      }
  }
.....  
// and somewhere to include test classes 
testRuntime project(":spring-common")
```

Answer (score 5):

The above solution works, but not for the latest version `1.0-rc3` of Gradle.

```
     task testJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: testClasses) {
       baseName = "test-${project.archivesBaseName}"

       // in the latest version of Gradle 1.0-rc3
       // sourceSets.test.classes no longer works
       // It has been replaced with 
       // sourceSets.test.output

       from sourceSets.test.output
     }
```

Answer (score 5):

If ProjectA contains the test code you wish to use in ProjectB and ProjectB wants to use *artifacts* to include the test code, then ProjectB's *build.gradle* would look like this:

```
dependencies {

  testCompile("com.example:projecta:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:tests")

}
```

Then you need to add an `archives` command to the `artifacts` section in ProjectA's build.gradle:

```
task testsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: testClasses) {
    classifier = 'tests'
    from sourceSets.test.output
}

configurations {
    tests
}

artifacts {
    tests testsJar
    archives testsJar
}

jar.finalizedBy(testsJar)
```

Now when ProjectA's artifacts are published to your artifactory they will include a *-tests* jar. This *-tests* jar can then be added as a testCompile dependency for ProjectB (as shown above).

Answer (score 0):

For Gradle `1.5`

```
task testJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: testClasses) {
    from sourceSets.test.java
    classifier "tests"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android on the latest gradle version (I'm currently on 2.14.1) you just need to add the below in Project B to get all the test dependencies from Project A.

```
dependencies {
  androidTestComplie project(path: ':ProjectA')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {    
    testImplementation project(':project_name')
}
```