# Including subproject project test sources through gradle

Tags: android, build, gradle, dependencies, multi-project

My structure is like this

```
Top Level Project (A)
-> src
    -> main
    -> test
-> Sub project (B)
    -> main
    -> test
```

In my dependencies for project A I have `compile project(":ProjectB")`, which works as expected for the `main` sources (brings in any dependencies referenced in project B, also brings in its sources). However `testCompile project(":ProjectB")` does not work as expected (does not bring in `test` sources and `test` dependencies).

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644011/multi-project-test-dependencies-with-gradle) is exactly what I want, however there are no answers for the latest version of gradle.

Notes: I'm running into this issue on an Android project with a submodule subproject. I'm using `androidTestCompile project(":ProjectB")`.