# Depend on main and test code for same Gradle dependency project

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I maintain at least 2 Java Gradle projects. Let's say that I have a common project named **A** and another project **B** that depends on **A**. **A** is technically common to many other projects, but that isn't a minor detail to my problem. Anyways, the current situation is that **B** declares a dependency on A as a plain-old external dependency in its build.gradle file, like so:

```
compile group:'com.example', name: 'A', version: '0.1'
```

We have code specific to tests in **A** that we share with **B** by placing it in *src/main/java*. This code has to stay in **A** instead of **B** because there are other projects depending on A that use this test code. I'd like to avoid putting the code in this directory because it has no purpose being deployed to production, due to its test-only nature. Also, simply moving the code from **A** to **B** wouldn't be possible because other projects in my organization depend on the same code and I want to avoid code duplication. I would rather move this test code in **A** to *src/test/java*, but then it won't be published to **A**'s JAR file.

Thus, I am trying to pursue a solution where this code lives in *src/test/java* in **A** and is deployed in a test-only JAR file. There are posts that discuss possible solutions, such as [this blog post](https://softnoise.wordpress.com/2014/09/07/gradle-sub-project-test-dependencies-in-multi-project-builds/) or SOF posts such as [Multi-project test dependencies with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644011/multi-project-test-dependencies-with-gradle) and [Multi-project test dependencies with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644011/multi-project-test-dependencies-with-gradle). **HOWEVER**, I continuous run into a problem caused by the fact that I am not maintaining a multi-project Gradle build, but rather two completely separate single-project Gradle builds, and this cannot change.

Where I am at right now is that I am configuring build.gradle for **A** in the exact way suggested in the blog post, like so:

```
configurations {
    testOutput.extendsFrom testCompile
}

task jarTest (type: Jar, dependsOn: testClasses) {
    from sourceSets.test.output
    classifier = 'test'
}

artifacts {
    testOutput jarTest
}
```

And then I have **A** declared as both `compile` and `testCompile` dependencies in build.gradle of **B**:

```
compile(group: 'com.example', name: 'A', version: '0.1')
testCompile(group: 'com.example', name: 'A', version: '0.1', configuration: 'testOutput')
```

This doesn't work. I am not getting any of the `testCompile` dependencies visible in the test classpath for **B**; these testCompile dependencies are not being reported by `gradle dependencies` nor are recognized by my IDE's code search (IntelliJ). I threw up a Hail Mary and even tried to replace `configuration: 'testOutput'` with `classifier: 'test'`, but to no avail. Gradle documentation doesn't quite seem to help either, as it seems that my use case isn't really covered in their intended use cases.

Any way I can achieve my desired usage of Gradle, or am I stuck with exporting test-only code in the main JAR file of **A**? All help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm whether you're actually publishing the test artifacts as well as the normal artifacts?

Comment: What's the best way to do this? I tried to look at my gradle cache in `~/.gradle`, but it looks like this directory isn't organized in the easiest manner to navigate. Do I need to configure a publish to local Maven repo instead? Or any other advice?

Answer (score 0):

I would treat code that is only needed during testing exactly the same as libraries that are only used during testing (e.g. JUnit or Mockito): The code should be in a separate module with its own name.

So I suggest that you split **A** into two modules (of the same multi-project build):

- **A**
- **A-test-support**

The dependencies of **A** would have to change to:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile project(':A-test-support')
}
```

In **B** you have to use these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile(group: 'com.example', name: 'A', version: '0.1')
    testCompile(group: 'com.example', name: 'A-test-support', version: '0.1')
}
```