# Gradle multi project - sharing test code between modules

Tags: java, android, gradle

`ProjectA` contains an abstract unit test, `TestA`.

`ProjectB` has a test called `TestB`, which needs to extends from `TestA`, to fulfil the test requirements for this specific implementation.

I've added to the `build.gradle` configuration file on `ProjectB`, `ProjectA` as a dependency compilation test:

```
testCompile project(':ProjectA')
```

Also, as a dependency compilation:

```
compile project(':ProjectA')
```

Although I'm able to extend from `TestA`, when I try to run `TestB` I get the next error:

```
error: cannot find symbol class TestA
```

So, is there any way to share test code between modules?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add include under the settings file for the root project?

Comment: You mean if in the top level build.gradle are defined as dependencies both modules? If so, yes, I did that.

Comment: The settings.gradle file for project B should have something like include ':projectA'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644011/multi-project-test-dependencies-with-gradle) you should add dependency on test sources like this:

```
compileTestJava.dependsOn tasks.getByPath(':projectA:testClasses')
testCompile files(project(':projectA').sourceSets.test.output.classesDir)
```

Comment: Can you give an example for how to do this for `androidTest`s with kotlin?

Comment: This is incorrect:
1) The second line implies the first; you don't need both.
2) This will result in the tests from projectA also being run in this project

Comment: Updated example to the latest Gradle version?