# Gradle project dependencies

Tags: gradle, dependencies, build-dependencies

I have 3 separate Gradle projects - **x** depends on **y** depending on **z**.

**x/settings.gradle**

```
include ':y'
project(':y').projectDir = new File('../y')
```

**x/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

**y/settings.gradle**

```
include ':z'
project(':z').projectDir = new File('../z')
```

**y/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
    compile project(':z')
}
```

When I run `gradlew build` in **x** directory, I get error

```
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Temp\idea\y\build.gradle' line: 4

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':y'.
  Project with path ':z' could not be found in project ':y'.
```

But running `gradlew build` in **y** directory is successful.

How should I configure **x** and **y** to avoid **y**'s dependencies affect **x**?

Comment: You're not supposed to have multiple settings.gradle file in a project.

Comment: Well, is there another way to create such a chain of dependencies?

Comment: Sure. The unique settings.gradle defines all the projects included in the build. Dependencies are declared in each project build file.

Comment: How can I define z's project path in y/build.gradle instead of y/settings.gradle?

Comment: Have you read the gradle manual about multi-project builds? It explains everything, including the structure.

Comment: you need to have a root-project, under that you have x,y,z projects, then the project dependency would be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how multi project builds work in Gradle.

In short, you cannot have multiple `settings.gradle`, only one at the root of the parent project.

In that settings file, you will define the different modules:

```
include ':x', ':y', ':z'
```

Note that the above implicitly assumes the 3 projects are located in folders named `x`, `y` and `Z` as siblings of the `settings.gradle` file.

The Gradle wrapper should be also defined at that root level and nowhere else.

And without changing the `build.gradle` file in each project, invoking `./gradlew build` in that root folder should produce what you expect.

Have a look at the [Gradle documentation on multi project builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same project dependency setup `x` -> `y` -> `z` and had to use the following `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` to get each project to build on its own and run own tests:

`z` `build.gradle` has no internal project dependencies or `settings.gradle`

`y` `build.gradle` has

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(':z')
```

`y` `settings.gradle` has

```
include ':z'
project(':z').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../z')
```

`x` `build.gradle` has

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(':y')
  implementation project(':z')
```

`x` `settings.gradle` has

```
include ':z'
project(':z').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../z')
include ':y'
project(':y').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../y')
```

This is the only way, so far, that I could get project `y` to build independently and run tests, and then get project `x` to build independently and run tests. Otherwise, without the `z` in the `x` `settings.gradle` I was getting:

```
Project with path ':z' could not be found in root project 'x'.
```

and without the `z` in the `x` `build.gradle` getting:

```
package does not exist
```

and

```
cannot find symbol
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677977/gradle-multi-project-package-not-found) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47598848/spring-boot-multi-module-project-with-gradle-doesnt-build) question helped as I also added to `x` and `y` `build.gradle` files

```
bootJar {
  enabled = false
}

jar {
  enabled = true
}
```