# Gradle Multi Project - Package not found

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I'm working with Java and grade to build the project. The following is the structure:

`Root-Project:
    /modules
        /rest-api
        /library-api`

My root build.gradle:

```
allprojects {

    apply plugin: 'base'
}
```

My root gradle.settings:

```
rootProject.name = 'RootProject'

include "rest-api"
include "library-api"

project(':rest-api').projectDir = new File('modules/rest-api')
project(':library-api').projectDir = new File('modules/library-api')
```

My rest project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion="2.0.4.RELEASE"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'example.com'
mainClassName = 'RestApi'
version = '0.9.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':library-api')
    .
    .
    .
}
```

My rest project grade.settings:

```
include "library-api"

project(':library-api').projectDir = new File('../library-api')
```

My library build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion="2.0.4.RELEASE"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'example.com'
mainClassName = 'AppRunner'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

For some reason, one of the packets inside 'library-api' is not being included into the rest-api classpath, and the, I'm having this error:

error: package library.crud does not exist

and all other classes inside it are not found too. The other classes are fine. Is it any kind cache problem ?? This package was the last think I included on the library.

Thanks all,
/Yore

Comment: Problem solved using the first answer at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47598848/spring-boot-multi-module-project-with-gradle-doesnt-build

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding my own answer to this. Suppose you have a root project `R`. It may have the traditional `src/main/java` path to the source code.
For some reason, if you place a sub project `S` under the `java` directory, it loses access to the package names. Moving `S` under `src/main` fixed this for me. If someone knows why this is a problem please share your insight!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35429624)