# Gradle 4 - test dependency on another project's tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, build

I have the following multi project structure:

```
/
    build.gradle
    common/
        build.gradle
        src/main/
            resources/common.properties
            java/...
        src/test/
            resources/common.properties
            java/...
    app/
        build.gradle
        src/main/java/...
        src/test/java/...
    admin/
        build.gradle
        src/main/java/...
        src/test/java/...
```

`common` project contains some common methods and they have their own unit tests and one `CommonDefs` class which contains data loaded from `common.properties`. When running unit tests, the `common.properties` file from the test resources supposedly overrides the one in the main resources, and the tests do work as expected.

The problem begins when running unit tests for `app` and `admin` projects - which contain tests that use `CommonDefs` from the common project.

Up until now I've used a generic solution similar to the method [described in the following SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5648565/4183902) and it has worked perfectly for a couple years. This is what the root `build.gradle` contains:

```
allprojects {
    plugins.withType(JavaPlugin) {
        configurations {
            testOutput
        }

        dependencies {
            testOutput sourceSets.test.output
        }
    }
}
```

and `app/build.gradle` & `admin/build.gradle` both contain:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":common")
    testCompile project(path: ":common", configuration: "testOutput")
    // ...
}
```

I've decided it was time to upgrade Gradle (previously used 2.14.1), so I started testing the project against Gradle 4.2.1. Now every time I run the tests for `app` and `admin`, `CommonDefs` loads data from `src/main/resources/common.properties` instead of `src/test/resources/common.properties`.

I've tried printing the test classpath for the app project and it seems that Gradle 4.2.1 takes the common's main JAR first:

```
path\to\app\build\classes\java\test
path\to\app\build\resources\test
path\to\app\build\classes\java\main
path\to\app\build\resources\main
path\to\common\build\libs\common.jar
path\to\common\build\classes\java\test
path\to\common\build\resources\test
```

with Gradle 2.14.1 the result was:

```
path\to\app\build\classes\test
path\to\app\build\resources\test
path\to\app\build\classes\main
path\to\app\build\resources\main
path\to\common\build\classes\test
path\to\common\build\resources\test
path\to\common\build\libs\common.jar
```

Is there a way to tell the newer version of Gradle to prioritize the test output of `common` over its main output?

N.B

I also tried using the following in `app/build.gradle`:

```
evaluationDependsOn(":common")

dependencies {
    compile project(":common")
    testCompile project(":common").sourceSets.test.output
}
```

which seems to work, but it looks rather hacky and I'd like to stick to the solution with the configuration if possible.

Comment: Relying on classpath ordering is always a bad idea, is there any chance you could move `common.properties` to `$env/common.properties`? You could then have unique paths eg `prod/common/properties`, `uat/common.properties`, `unit-test/common.properties` and `integ-test/common.properties` etc. You could use a system property to choose the $env (defaulted to "prod" for backwards compatability)