# Can't get test fixtures to work in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-multi-project-build, java-test-fixtures

I've been using these answers to try to get a test class to be visible from subproject ":A:B" to ":A:C":

(https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-test-classes-needed-in-another-sub-project/13365/2)

([Multi-project test dependencies with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644011/multi-project-test-dependencies-with-gradle))

[using plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644011/multi-project-test-dependencies-with-gradle/60138176#60138176)

Using any of these methods still gives me a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on Project B. I'm using gradle 7.2.

Is there another way to expose test fixtures in gradle?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to add a third module, which then can be referenced as `testImplementation project()`.