# How to setup arch unit in a multi module project

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl, archunit

I am currently developing an Android app (= multi module gradle project).

I am trying to introduce ArchUnit, but I have problems accessing the test sourceset of all other modules....

As I am using kotlin and want to use kotlin reflection (= finding out if some classes are indeed internal) it would be good to have those classes on the classpath as well....

I started using `ClassFileImporter().importPackages("my.test")`

Note: I am using gradle Kotlin DSL

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644011/multi-project-test-dependencies-with-gradle

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I could come up with is the following:

I import the files via a path:

`ClassFileImporter().importPath(Paths.get(".."))`

(NOTE: `..` references the root project, I placed the test in the test sourceset of my Android "app")