# Run JUnit tests from another project using Gradle?

Tags: java, junit, gradle

**Question:** Is it possible to run JUnit tests located in one Gradle project, with dependencies from another project?

**Background**

Consider this multi-project setup:

```
product_1_configuration_with_tests/
feature_a_with_tests/
feature_b_with_tests/
common_integration_tests/
```

- For the sake of simplicity, the product project depends on the other three projects. No other dependencies exist.
- `common_integration_tests` contains integration tests common for all products, that *must* be run in the context (classpath/dependencies) of the product.
- `common_integration_tests` can not have any dependencies to any other projects.
- The behavior of the common integration tests differ depending on what is on the runtime classpath.

How can such common integration tests be run?

**Attempts**

Ideally I'd like the test task to be defined in the product project. I have tried including the integration test in the suite:

```
// In product_1_configuration_with_tests/build.gradle
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
  include '**/MyIntegrationTest.class'
}
```

Since the test task does not find the test which resides in another module, no tests are executed.

Comment: I have seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8730087/384617) but the answer does not help in this case.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the exact problem, what have you tried, why didn't it work, etc? Also, what are the exact dependencies between the projects?

Comment: I have tried clarifying my question. Is it more understandable now?

Answer (score 0):

Either you declare the integration test sources as a separate source set of the `product_1_configuration_with_tests` project (giving up on the `common_integration_tests` project), or you declare a dependency from `common_integration_tests` on `product_1_configuration_with_tests`. In a greenfield project, the former would be the preferable approach, but the latter will work as well. Other solutions are needlessly complicated.

> common_integration_tests can not have any dependencies to any other projects.

Why?

Comment: It can more specifically not have any dependencies on any product projects. This is because we want to be able to reuse the integration tests in many products, and we can't have dependencies between our products.

Comment: That changes the game. Are the products part of the same Gradle build?

Comment: Nope, each product is built separately (but all are built using Gradle).

Comment: In that case, you'd publish the tests as a Jar, and pull them into the products as `testCompile` dependencies. Since a `Test` task also requires a `testClassesDir`, you'd probably have to add a `Copy` task that unpacks the test Jar into some directory and configure the `Test` task accordingly. You might find further details at http://forums.gradle.org (the question has been asked before).