# gradle pull test jar from other project

Tags: maven, gradle

I have a multi-project setup in maven and trying to switch to gradle. I am trying to figure out how to have one project's test dependencies include another project's test jar.  Right now i have the following in ProjectA:

```
packageTests = task packageTests(type: Jar) {
  classifier = 'tests'
  from sourceSets.test.output
}

tasks.getByPath(":ProjectA:jar").dependsOn(packageTests)
```

And in ProjectB i have:

```
testCompile project(path: ':ProjectA', classifier: 'tests')
```

I see that my tests are failing to compile.  Looks like they are missing classes defined in the test jar.  When I check the build dir, i see that the ProjectA-0.1.56-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar is present.

In maven I had the following for ProjectA:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

And this for ProjectB:

```
<!-- Testing -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProjectA</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.56-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
</dependency>
```

How can I get this to work just like maven?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144325/gradle-test-dependency and there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644011/multi-project-test-dependencies-with-gradle

Answer (score 2):

What you will end up with is something like

```
tasks.create( [
  name: 'testJar',
  type: Jar,
  group: 'build',
  description: 'Assembles a jar archive containing the test classes.',
  dependsOn: tasks.testClasses
] ) {
  manifest = tasks.jar.manifest
  classifier = 'tests'
  from sourceSets.test.output
}

// for test dependencies between modules
// usage: testCompile project(path: ':module', configuration: 'testFixtures')
configurations { testFixtures { extendsFrom testRuntime } }

artifacts {
  archives testJar
  testFixtures testJar
}

tasks.uploadArchives.dependsOn testJar
```