# Dependencies not copied into jar (in Gradle)

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

**TL;DR I expected the dependencies of a module to be built into its .jar, but they don't appear to be.**

I'm using Gradle to build a project. I have two subprojects, `app` (an Android module) and `tests` (a Java module), as created by IntelliJ.

Since I want to use the classes defined in `app` in the contents of `tests`, I've added the appropriate dependency. Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5153162/1040915), I've got the following setup:

app/build.gradle:

```
...
task jarTask(type: Jar) {
    baseName ="${project.archivesBaseName}"
    from android.sourceSets.main.java
}

configurations {
    jarConfiguration
}

artifacts {
    jarConfiguration jarTask
}
```

tests/build.gradle

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    testCompile project(path: ':app', configuration: 'jarConfiguration')
}
```

However, one of the classes in `app` imports `org.json.JSONObject`. Since this is provided by the Android SDK, `app` can find it fine - but when I try to run tests, I get (in `:tests:compileTestJava`) "package org.json does not exist". However, if I update tests/build.gradle to be

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    testCompile project(path: ':app', configuration: 'jarConfiguration')
    testCompile 'org.json:json:20090211'
}
```

(See [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20090211)) then the tests run correctly.

This wasn't what I expected - if a .jar doesn't package up its dependencies, then any project which depends on that .jar must also explicitly depend on the transitive dependencies - wouldn't this cause dependency definitions to rapidly increase?

Comment: Why do you want the application classes in the library Jar? Seems like the wrong way around.

Comment: The app is an Android application which will receive JSON from a server (also part of the project). The app contains classes to represent these JSON responses. As part of the tests, I want to spin up a test instance of the server, get responses from it, and check that they can be correctly deserialized into these classes. Thus, I need the tests to depend on the app classes.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the concept of a "fatJar" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22640847/1040915) and [here](http://fw-geekycoder.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/how-to-create-jar-with-dependencies-in.html), which seems to be synonymous with a "jar with dependencies" - but changing my app/build.gradle to read

```
...
task jarTask(type: Jar) {
    baseName ="test-${project.archivesBaseName}"
    from android.sourceSets.main.java
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    baseName = project.name + "-all"
    from {configurations.compile.collect {it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)}}
    with jarTask
}

configurations {
    jarConfiguration
}

artifacts {
    jarConfiguration fatJar
}
```

still gives an error that `package org.json does not exist`. This appears to be because `org.json` is not explicitly called out as a dependency in the app/build.gradle file. With the following app/build.gradle, my project built and ran tests as expected:

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.json:json:20090211'
}

task jarTask(type: Jar) {
    baseName ="${project.archivesBaseName}"
    from android.sourceSets.main.java
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    baseName = project.name + "-all"
    from {configurations.compile.collect {it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)}}
    with jarTask
}

configurations {
    jarConfiguration
}

artifacts {
    jarConfiguration fatJar
}
```

(Note that if you just want the fatJar task, you can simply set `from files({configurations.compile.collect {it.isDirector() ? it : zipTree(it)}}, android.sourceSets.main.java)`