# Closure defined in root not visible in child

Tags: gradle, closures, multi-project

I have  root project and subproject (`:child`).
Root build looks like like this:

```
def foo = {
  println("foo")
}

allprojects {
  task bar << {
    println(project.name + ":bar")
  }

  afterEvaluate {
   foo()
  }
}
```

Running `gradle bar` prints:

```
foo
foo
:bar
:child:bar
child:bar
parent:bar
```

This make sense. However, IRL I need `foo` to be called by the child's build file (because I want it to be called only by some of the submodules). 
The [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html) seems to be clear enough: `In a multi-project build, sub-projects inherit the properties and methods of their parent project`

However, moving the "afterEvaluate" block above into `child/build.gradle` results in an error: `Could not find method foo() for arguments [] on project ':child' of type org.gradle.api.Project`.

Why does this happen and how do I fix this? I have tried a whole bunch of different variations - moving the `def` around (to `buildscript`, `allprojects`, to `ext`, to `allprojects.ext`, making it a variable in ext, instead of a method etc.), referring to it differently (as `rootProject.foo`, `rootProject.foo()`, `ext.foo()` etc.) - nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vars need to be declared in the ext namespace for them to be propagated downstream. Try:

```
ext.foo = {
  println("foo")
}
```

ref: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html

Comment: Ok, looks like this works. Now, next question is, how do I run it after _all_ modules are evaluated, not just this one? It looks like my next problem is that child/foo is executed before another child knows that it depends on this one. Is there a trick to fix that? I tried replacing it with `rootProject.afterEvaluate` but that seems to just do nothing at all :/