# How to remove a dependency from project class path only while running junit?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gradle, junit

My application has a dependency to jaxb-api.jar and jaxb-impl.jar. How can I remove those two dependencies from project class path only while running `junit`?
(I need the same jars available in class path for application to run. Need to remove only during `junit` test case execution.)
Edit: I am using Gradle

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: I am using gradle. The problem is I need those dependencies while running the application and need to exclude while junit runtime only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle Test Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144325/gradle-test-dependency)

Comment: @fantaghirocco its not the same! Adding a dependency for test class alone is fine(We can add under testCompile). But how to remove a dependency for test class alone?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using maven, it should help to set the "scope" of the dependencies. You can find information about Scopes under this link: https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-dependency-scopes/

Comment: It is recommended to include necessary parts of the reference link in the answer