# Defining testJar task for Gradle 3.x/4.x

Tags: gradle

As described in [Gradle Test Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144325/gradle-test-dependency) and [Multi-project test dependencies with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644011/multi-project-test-dependencies-with-gradle), the solution for cross-project test dependencies is to define something like

```
task testJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: testClasses) {
    from sourceSets.test.java
    classifier "tests"
}

configurations {
    tests
}

artifacts {
    tests testJar
}
```

in the depended-upon project and

```
dependencies {
    testCompile project(path: ':aProject', configuration: 'tests')
}
```

in the dependent project.

But the answers there mention Gradle 1.x, a few 2.x. In Gradle 3.5 this gives me

> Error:(22, 0) Could not get unknown property 'testClasses' for project ':communicator-api' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

and removing the `dependsOn: testClasses` gives

> Error:(23, 0) Could not get unknown property 'sourceSets' for task ':communicator-api:testsJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.

How to define `testJar` in Gradle 3.x or 4.x? Or is there a more standard solution now?

Comment: I assume that you did not apply the Java Plugin to your project because it adds both the task and the `sourceSets` container which are missing according to your error messages.

Comment: The issue was with ordering. I was trying to do this in root project's `subprojects` to avoid code duplication, so it was happening before the Java plugin was applied.

Comment: And apparently what I needed is `afterEvaluate`.